# How to enable auditing in mongodb for windows environment

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I would like to enable auditing feature for mongodb in windows environment. As per mongodb documentation [Configure Auditing](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-auditing/) we cannot use audit parameters like --auditDestination in windows. Is there an alternate way to enable auditing in windows.  My requirement is whenever there is DML operation in mongodb i need to capture in a audit table for changed records. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Audit events are only available in MongoDB **Enterprise** and not the **Community** edition (as of version 3.2) .

But what you mention here is not what the documentation says. MongoDB allows for 4 different destinations for audit events (again as of version 3.2) . It only says one of the following 4 options is not available in Windows.

1. **syslog**: This is not available in Windows.
2. **console**: prints the audit events to the console.

> mongod --dbpath data/db --auditDestination console

3. **JSON file**: prints the audit events to a JSON file.

> mongod --dbpath data/db --auditDestination file --auditFormat JSON
>   --auditPath data/db/auditLog.json

4. **BSON file**: prints the audit events to a BSON file.

> mongod --dbpath data/db --auditDestination file --auditFormat BSON  --auditPath data/db/auditLog.bson